# Is "zu Arbeiten" or "zum Arbeiten" correct in this case?

Tags: usage

In an attempt to translate "I want to start work", I said:

> Ich will **zum** Arbeiten anfangen.

But I was corrected to:

> Ich will **zu** Arbeiten anfangen.

Please tell me if you do or do not agree with this correction, and why.

Here are only some of the related examples from DWDS:

> Schizopolis, 1996 (Filmuntertitel)
> Eigentlich wollte ich wieder **mit dem Arbeiten anfangen**, wenn Emily geboren ist,... aber das hat nicht wirklich geklappt.

> Born Yesterday, 1950 (Filmuntertitel)
> Ich hab mit 10 Jahren **das Arbeiten angefangen**.

> dann habe ich gleich am nächsten Tag **das Arbeiten angefangen**.

> Berliner Zeitung, 15.09.2000
> Die **Arbeiten** haben bereits **angefangen**.

> Wo ich überall meine Finger drin hab @ Xooyoo. blog.xooyoo.de, 2010-10-09
> Seit gut 2 Jahren darf ich mich Dipl.- Ing. (FH) nennen, und nach 26 Jahren Bildung sollte man doch mal ein klein wenig **zu Arbeiten anfangen**.

Comment: One of these examples is not like the others: in "die Arbeiten haben angefangen", "die Arbeiten" is the subject of "anfangen". It is rightfully capitalized as the nom. plur. of the *noun* "Arbeit". It is not a form of the *verb* "arbeiten", so it doesn't really count towards your list.

Comment: In addition to what @marquinho already wrote, the last example is incorrect capitalization, correct would be "... sollte man doch mal ein klein wenig zu **a**rbeiten anfangen."

Comment: Zu Arbeiten dieses Hauses äußere ich mich nicht. - Naja, sie müssten erstmal anfangen zu arbeiten. - Willst Du Ihnen zuarbeiten? - Nein, ich schaffe es nicht zur Arbeit dahin zu kommen, auch keine externen Zuarbeiten. - Ja, man muss überhaupt erst zum Arbeiten kommen können. (a bit absurd, but could be a conversation with several of the uses)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither. It must be

> Ich will zu arbeiten anfangen.

or

> Ich will anfangen zu arbeiten.

The verb *anfangen* can take a zu-Infinitiv as a complement. It's what you want to start doing. This is especially common if you want to add additional information.

> Ich will anfangen, an meiner Hausaufgabe zu arbeiten.

Mind the comma. You have to make it a clause as soon you add additional information.

If you wanted to use the nominalized infinitive of the verb *arbeiten* instead, you had to use the correct preposition for that. The verb *anfangen* can take an adverbial introduced with *mit*.

> Ich will mit dem Arbeiten anfangen.

> Ich will mit dem Arbeiten an meiner Hausaufgabe anfangen.

In this phrasing, a clause is not necessary for adding additional information.

And finally, in this context, you may use the noun *die Arbeit* as well.

> Ich will mit der Arbeit anfangen.

> Ich will mit der Arbeit an meiner Hausaufgabe anfangen.

Comment: I am not so concerned with what I should do, as I am concerned with why others do what they do. zu Arbeiten and zum Arbeiten are used extensively, and I wish to know why, in every case, if possible.

Comment: Get *zu Arbeiten* out of your mind. That one is from the noun *die Arbeit* and super rare. What you need to tell apart is *zu arbeiten* and *das Arbeiten*. Both are made from the verb *arbeiten*. The first is the *zu-Infinitiv* and the latter is the nominalized infinive. The zu-Infinitiv is good for giving shortcut arguments to verbs that allow it, and for infinitive clauses. The nominalized infinitive is good for every occasion where a noun would come in handy. *Zum Arbeiten* is just a use case of *das Arbeiten* used as an argument for the preposition *zu*.

Comment: Please also note the double function of *zu* as either a particle of the *zu-Infinitiv* and as a preposition. Same as in English, this accounts for endless confusion.

Comment: Seems like the right way to view these many variations. German is particularly hard because German speakers appear to make up the language as they go along, at times. Thanks.

Comment: Certainly not. You first have to have a clear concept whether you use/have a noun or a verb. Then the rest follows stringently

Comment: Beispiel für das von Janka zu Recht(?) als selten benannte Plural von 'die Arbeit': Zu (den) Arbeiten von Franz Kafka finde ich eine große Auswahl an Rezensionen. Concerning (the) works of Franz Kafka, I find a large amount of reviews

Answer (score 2):

It is good that you are a using a good dictionary, but using a dictionary that is primarily aimed at native speakers requires practice and some grammar knowledge. Also, you could make better use of the actual dictionary. In this case, the important part is the verb [anfangen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/anfangen). At the beginning of 1a of the entry you find three relevant ways to use it:

- etwas anfangen
- anfangen etwas zu tun
- mit etwas anfangen

The second variant requires an infinitive, the other two a noun. That noun can be a nominalised verb. The second variant is what makes this correct (notice the lower case “arbeiten”):

> Ich will zu arbeiten anfangen.

You have also found examples of the other two variants in the corpus.